# Removing a variable number of characters from front of a string in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to remove a changing number of characters from a string right now I have it as
    set /A VAR=%VAR:~%Num%%
is there any way you can think to make this work.
I am currently trying to it with a goto loop so I can still reference the variable
If you want to look at my code in context you can look at it on github at [thumbdown.camojackson.com](http://thumbdown.camojackson.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Well without seeing all your code I can give you some options.

For starters you do not use the /A option to do string manipulation.

1) Use delayed expansion.

```
set VAR=!VAR:~%Num%!
```

2) Use the CALL command to get an extra phase of expansion

```
CALL set VAR=%%VAR:~%Num%%%
```

Comment: The first option you gave me just returns '!VAR:~2!' and the second option returns '%VAR:~2!Num%%%'

Comment: @JacksonBorneman The first option requires you to enable delayed expansion.  Your second option example does not look right.  It should not have an exclamation point in it at all which means you are not using the code I gave your correctly.  And like I noted, without seeing all your code, I can't say for sure which option will work or is better.